# Integral of $\frac{1}{(x^2+2)^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Ive been struggling to find the integral $\frac{1}{(x^2+2)^3}$  by using the integral $I_n=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^n}$.
(assume I know how to solve $I_n$ by a recursive way.
Ive tried to make it to the form of In but without any success, any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** :

You can notice that : $$\frac{1}{(x^2+2)^3}=\frac{1}{(2(\frac{x^2}{2}+1))^3}=\frac{1}{8((\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2+1)^3}=\frac{\frac{1}{8}}{((\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2+1)^3}$$
Now you should be able to use a result about $I_n$.

Comment: yeah I figured that out few moments after I published the question. I feel stupid about this question. thanks anyway!